# Efficient way of converting contours into numpy array mask in scikit-image?

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

I there an efficient way of converting contours into numpy array mask? For example, if I have 2 contours represent a donut shape, one is inner contour line, the other one is outer contour line. Can I somehow rasterize it into a numpy array where the elements in the array that fall into the donut shape would be marked as True or 1, the other elements as False or 0.

I found a way to do it in opencv. But I am wondering if I can do the same in scikit-image?

[Edit]: contour is stored as list of tuples (x, y)

Many thanks.

Comment: If by contours you mean a dim-2 array (as is the case with meshgrid), you can reshape the array to be a dim-1 array via numpy.

Comment: An example would help, but I think what you want can be achieved by labeling and regionprops.

Answer (score 2):

The scikit-image tool grid_points_in_poly should solve this fairly efficiently and let you go from a contour to a mask efficiently:

```
skimage.measure.grid_points_in_poly(shape, verts)
```

> Test whether points on a specified grid are inside a polygon. For each
>   (r, c) coordinate on a grid, i.e. (0, 0), (0, 1) etc., test whether
>   that point lies inside a polygon.

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.grid_points_in_poly

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)